# How to set default value for ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have here a form for posting a simple data, I want to have a default string value for my input but why doesn't it appear, I tried `ng-value` but it does not work too. How can I set a default string to my ng-model?

```
<form name="regForm" ng-submit="register.regUser(regData);">

<input type="text" ng-model="register.regData.branch_name" name="branch_name" value="This is a string">   
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: You ave to initialize `register.regData.branch_name` inside your controller. `register.regData.branch_name = myDefaultValue`;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
<form name="regForm" ng-submit="register.regUser(regData);">

<input type="text" ng-model="register.regData.branch_name" name="branch_name"  ng-init="register.regData.branch_name='This is a string'">   
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-init` directive to set default value like following:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
<form name="regForm" ng-submit="register.regUser(regData);">

<input type="text" ng-model="register.regData.branch_name" name="branch_name"  ng-init="register.regData.branch_name='This is a string'">   
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
</div>
```